# Looking for JavaScript design advice - Scroll through days using ajax

Tags: javascript

I'm 2 months old in JavaScript but I've made pretty solid progress by altering existing code. Now I'd like to implement a specific functionality that I depicted in the image below:

[image: Endless Scrolling with AJAX]

I'd like this function to shadow the rest of the page and focus on the Scrolling. I'd like to be able to click the arrows and scroll through the days, and see them slide left or right as they fade off the screen.

I think I can figure out the data structure to hold the data and the php to get it, but I don't know where to start for the animation.

**Questions:**

1. How can I search existing JavaScript with similar functionality? My searches have yielded nothing, and I'm sure there must be an efficient way to find useful code.
2. Does anyone have any recommendations for functionality like this? Maybe something similar that I can convert.
3. If I need to build this from scratch, what things do I need to look into with respect to the animation and (if it's not css) the fading aspect of this?

Comment: Did you try Jssor slider? You can have look here http://www.jssor.com/demos/banner-slider.html

Comment: There is a lot of source code. I'll have to take a deeper look. Worst case: I can look at the animations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the container box-shadow to inset `box-shadow 0 0 100px black;`